# Django: Integrating Avangate IPN

Tags: django, paypal-ipn, payment, payment-processing

Does anyone have example code showing how to process the Avangate IPN (Instant Payment Notification) in a Django app? In particular, I'm interested in seeing examples of creating the hash signature for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look into Django satchmo and see their implementation http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/ Its a shopping cart framework.